# MongoDB - Get an unique array from two queries

Tags: database, mongodb

First of all sorry if the title does not reflect what I really need to do.

Imagine a collection that represents what products sell which vendor. Let´s simplify like:

```
{_id, productID, VendorID, Price, Stock}
```

For example, we could have:

```
{_id: 1 ,productID: 1, vendorID: A, price: 0, stock: 0},
{_id: 2 ,productID: 2, vendorID: A, price: 0, stock: 0},
{_id: 3 ,productID: 3, vendorID: A, price: 0, stock: 0},
{_id: 4 ,productID: 4, vendorID: A, price: 0, stock: 0},
{_id: 5 ,productID: 1, vendorID: B, price: 0, stock: 19},
{_id: 6 ,productID: 3, vendorID: B, price: 0, stock: 21}
```

The idea is that Vendor A is the Super Admin and the one who controls which products can be sold in the marketplace. That´s why all products sold by A have price = 0 and stock = 0.

What I am trying to get within the same query is. When Vendor B is logged:

- List all the items that A is selling.
- But if a product is sold by B, then I should return it instead of the A-one.

The result would look like:

```
    {_id: 2 ,productID: 2, vendorID: A, price: 0, stock: 0},
    {_id: 4 ,productID: 4, vendorID: A, price: 0, stock: 0},
    {_id: 5 ,productID: 1, vendorID: B, price: 0, stock: 19},
    {_id: 6 ,productID: 3, vendorID: B, price: 0, stock: 21}
```

Do you have any idea how I can do it in a shot?

I can do the filter in the frontend but I would prefer doing like this in order to avoid problems with pagination for example.

Comment: So, your desired response for products with IDs 1,2,3,4 is array of records with IDs 5,2,6,4 right?

Comment: Yes @Xeelley. I updated the post.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that all products sold by `A` **always** have price = 0 and stock = 0, you can do the following trick:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    vendorID: {
      $in: [
        "A",
        "B"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  $sort: {
    productID: 1,
    price: -1
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$productID",
    "product": {
      $first: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PEHd_cfSRoN)

- by [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) you are looking for all products owned by default vendor (`A`) and target vendor (`B`).
- by [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) you group products by `productID` and by price in each group, so product sold by `A` will be last one in each group
- by [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) you extract product from each group
- using [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) it will be first product (with higher price, so product sold by `A` will be matched only if no other products with same ID were sold).

DB documents will be aggregated by `$$ROOT` into `product` field, so you can map them using:

```js
// (javascript)
const productDocuments = aggregationResult.map(row => row.product);
```

**Notice:** product sold by `A` still can be extracted even if `B` sold product with same ID in cases when `B`'s product also have price = 0.